# CSS3 timed animation of background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am pretty new to CSS and HTML, but I am learning the ropes. Right now, I have a background image on my header section and I am trying to turn this into a slideshow with 3-4 images shuffling through on a timer.

I have seen some tutorials that use images through HTML, but the way I have set it up is I have my CSS property background-image set as my image.

If this doesnt make sense, here is the CSS

```
.global-header {
min-height:600px;
background-image: url("Assets/BGImages/head_sandwichman.jpg");
background-size: cover;
text-align: center; 
and the HTML

<header class="container global-header">
<div class="inner-w">
<div class='rmm' data-menu-style = "minimal">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="menu.html">MENU</a></li>
            <li><a href="findus.html">FIND US</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="large-logo-wrap">
        <img src="Assets/Logos/Giadaslogoindexwhitebig.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following

```
 <script>
//Here use Array of images ,which you want to show, Use path you want.
var images=new Array('Assets/BGImages/head_sandwichman1.jpg','Assets/BGImages/head_sandwichman2.jpg','Assets/BGImages/head_sandwichman3.jpg');
var nextimage=0;

doSlideshow();

function doSlideshow()
{

if(nextimage>=images.length)
    nextimage=0;

$('.global-header').css('background-image','url("'+images[nextimage++]+'")').fadeIn(500,function(){setTimeout(doSlideshow,1000);});

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would not be using HTML and CSS for carousel. While some cool experiments are out there I would shy away from using that on a production site. You will most likely be using jQuery. If you are new to front-end development and want to set up the slider and move on to the rest of your project, I'd recommend using a plugin.

Here is a popular jQuery plugin you can use:  http://dev7studios.com/plugins/nivo-slider/

If you want to learn how to create your own, try following a tutorial that creates a similar slider. Then try playing around with the code to get it to the exact state you want.

Here's a an example of said tutorial: http://paulmason.name/item/simple-jquery-carousel-slider-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I think depending on the animation you are doing depends on the technique you could use.

if you are sliding the images you could use CSS3 animations to slide between the images. But this means you would have to make one large image that contains all your images and you change the background image position on a cycle.

This might be of some help:

http://designshack.net/articles/css/infinitephotobanner/

or you could try setting different background classes and implementing a change of class on a timer using this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var seconds = 5000; // set in milliseconds
  var step = 1; // place to start
  var limit = 3; //limit of background images (remember that 0 is the start so 3 is for 4 background images)

  $(".global-header").addClass("banner"+step).fadeIn(1000);

  setInterval(function(){
    $(".global-header").fadeOut(500,function(){
       $(this).removeClass("banner"+step);
       step = (step > limit) ? 1 : step + 1;
      $(".global-header").addClass("banner"+step).fadeIn(1000);
    });
  },seconds);
});
```

And then use different class's for the background image. (I used .banner in this instance):

```
.banner1{
background:url(../images/something.jpg);
}
.banner2{
background:url(../images/somethingElse.jpg);
}
.banner3{
background:url(../images/soemthingElseAgain.jpg);
}
```

you can experiement with the different range of J-query effects, I used fadeIn for simplicity.

Hope this helps.